# Joda Time hour interval

Tags: android, jodatime, android-jodatime

I get time from server in format { "from" : "12-00", "to" : "01-00" }
Then, I parse it like this

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm").parseDateTime(dateString)
```

Then, I need to check if current time is in this hour range:

```
Interval(from, to).containsNow()
```

Interval constructor throws error because second date more than first
DateTime object time is 1970-01-01T12:00:00.000Z and 1970-01-01T01:00:00.000Z

How can I check if current hour is in hour range? Is there any hour range in Joda?

Comment: Are you working with 12-hour format time, or 24-hour format?

Comment: @deluxe1 24-hour format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using 24-hour format, you need to use the date as well. You are currently comparing 12:00 of 01-01-1970 (the Unix start Date) with 01:00 of the same day, and 12:00 is after 1:00 and that is an invalid interval.

Change the DateTime pattern to "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" or something else that works for you and contains both the date and the time that suits your needs. Then, you can make the check.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried to find workaround, but it seems there is no.